# How to check whether or not a camera app is the active activity by a service?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, camera, receiver

I wrote a background service which registers a "screen off" Broadcast Receiver. I would like my service to be able to identify whether or not the last active app (I means other app) is an app that uses the camera or not (such as default camera, photo wonder, google camera, line camera, etc.? Then I can control my service to what it should do.

Debug result from @FlyingPumba code

02-20 11:21:53.546 10627-10627/ I/CameraApp: Active App Name : My Camera App
02-20 11:21:53.556 10627-10627/ I/CameraApp: Camera app : com.sec.android.app.camera
02-20 11:21:53.556 10627-10627/ I/CameraApp: Camera app : com.google.android.GoogleCamera
02-20 11:21:53.566 10627-10627/ I/CameraApp: Camera app : com.fotoable.fotobeauty
02-20 11:21:53.566 10627-10627/ I/CameraApp: Camera app : com.commsource.beautyplus
02-20 11:21:53.566 10627-10627/ I/CameraApp: Camera app : com.venticake.retrica
02-20 11:21:53.566 10627-10627/ I/CameraApp: Camera app : com.joeware.android.gpulumera
02-20 11:21:53.566 10627-10627/ I/CameraApp: Camera app : com.ywqc.picbeauty
02-20 11:21:53.566 10627-10627/ I/CameraApp: Camera app : vStudio.Android.Camera360
02-20 11:21:53.566 10627-10627/ I/CameraApp: Camera app : com.almalence.night

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
// get the info from the currently running task
List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
Log.d("CameraApp", "Foreground Activity Name ::" + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());
ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
if (isCameraApp(componentInfo.getPackageName())) {
    // do your stuff
}

private boolean isCameraApp(CharSequence packageName) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // get activities that can resolve the image capture intent
    List<ResolveInfo> imageCaptureActivites = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    Log.i("CameraApp","Camera app :" + name.toString());
    for(ResolveInfo info : imageCaptureActivites) {
        if (info.activityInfo.packageName.contains(packageName.toString()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You will need this permission in your Manifed:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

Comment: Thank you @FlyingPumba isCameraApp() function is ok. but active app name is not as expected. It is always my app.  Let see my debug result above.